# How to show that $(a \text{ } mod \text{ } m)^2 \text{ } mod \text{ } m = a^2 \text{ } mod \text{ } m$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have seen this small equality used in a proof that I was reading and I wanted to show that it is true. It seems like an easy problem but I didn't know how to start. Can you show me how is it true?

Comment: Let $a  = k\cdot m + b$ where $0< b \le m-1$, and try writing out both sides.

Comment: It seems that this is telling you that if $b=a \mod m$, then $b^2=a^2 \mod m$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I solved the problem by using letting $a = km + b$.

Comment: The language “$a$ mod $m = b$" is poorly suited to mathematical statements, as your title shows. So much better to use the mathematical notation “$a\equiv b\pmod m$”, as @JulianMejia hints.